# how to change the height of UI semantic

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, height, semantic-ui

I use Semantic UI and embed to an iFrame tag for a video. but i want to change the height of semantic UI.

```
    <div className="video_box ui embed">
                    <iframe
                        width="100%"
                        height="100%"
                        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tkLLGHa8XuI?start=23"
                        frameborder="0"
                        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                        allowfullscreen
                    ></iframe>
                </div>
```

this is my css file. I am trying to change the height here

```
video_box {
display: flex;
width: 50%;
height: 500px; /*This is not working*/
margin-right: 10px;
align-items: center;
```

}

Comment: You need iframe height in px like - iframe {height:500px}

Comment: `<div className="video_box ui embed">
      <iframe
     width="100%"
       height="500px"
      ></iframe>
     </div>`

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to set the height of the iframe too, so:

```
.iframe, .video_box {
height: 500px;
};
```

Comment: i changed to  <frame height="500px" />, but still not woking.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```css
.video_box {
display: flex;
width: 50%;
height: 500px;
margin-right: 10px;
align-items: center;
}
iframe {
  height:500px
}
```

```html
<div className="video_box ui embed">
                    <iframe
                        width="100%"
                        height="100%"
                        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tkLLGHa8XuI?start=23"
                        frameborder="0"
                        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                        allowfullscreen
                    ></iframe>
                </div>
```